# Firefox not handling Google import font?

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, google-font-api

I'm using this in my css

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cardo&family=Libre+Caslon+Display&display=swap');
```

then further on

```
body {
    font-family: 'Cardo','Baskerville', serif;
...
```

Chrome displays this just fine, i.e., the Cardo font in text. But Firefox (115.7.0esr)  switches things around. FontFinder extension shows

```
...
Font font-family (stack)     serif "Cardo" "Baskerville"
Font being Rendered          System Default      100.0% (local)
...
```

and it's showing this wrong font as italic as well. How is this being munged by Firefox? I'm guessing Firefox is not doing the font import from Google properly? Does it require a woff addition to my css? What would that look like?

Comment: Please add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - I can't reproduce this error. Are you sure you're not overriding the font-family style rules somewhere in your CSS?

Comment: Yes, sorry, try https://wuthering.uk/test.html I do not have this problem on my Lenovo tablet, BTW.

Comment: Your font is displayed as italic since it's wrapped in a `<i>`  tag – formerly used as a standard italicize tag. Nowadays you should prefer the `<em>` tag or just apply italic styles to your headings directly.  Keep in mind a google font style query like `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cardo` does only load the regular (font-weight:400; font-style:normal)/upright font. So you're seeing the result of a "faux italic" (synthesized slanted pseudo-italic) that's quite likely producing the different renderings. Besides, better trust the browser devtools (firefox or chromium).

Comment: The offending line `<h2 id="orgab650e8"><i>To begin</i></h2>` should not be a problem. I take it out and it's still italicizing everything. AND I'm seeing unwanted italicizing on other sites too. This is some strange Firefox bug.

Comment: Sorry I can't reproduce this error. Here is a [test with extracted css](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/OJqZEML) Does it also italicize the fonts? If so it It may be a bug in this specific firefox version. Could it be you're using any special extensions (e.g. add blockers) or configs that may block the font loading?